# Itanium assembly programming resources?

Tags: c, architecture, assembly, itanium

Are there any good Itanium assembly language tutorials?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe suprising, but I recommend [IA-64 Linux Kernel: Design and Implementation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130610143)

Even though technically is not an Itanium assembly book, it covers that quite well, and explains the details of IA-64 operations, like its memory model, interupts etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

While not at all comprehensive, a nice little resource you should look at (especially if you're looking at doing anything with ia64 on Windows) is the help file for the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/DevTools/Debugging/default.mspx) - it has a few pages on ia64 basics in the "Processor Architecture" chapter.  Like I said it's not at all comprehensive, but it's a nice little intro.